# how to access object in variable react native

Tags: react-native

how can i access for example region object or setState in watchID in componentDidMount? after setState, this.state.error output in componentDidMount is false but in render is true.
how access to region object?

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
    error: false
  };
}

componentDidMount () {
  watchID = Geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
    let region = {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      long: position.coords.longitude
    };
    this.setState({
      latitude: region.lat || this.state.latitude,
      longitude: region.long || this.state.longitude });
  },
  (error) => {
    this.setState({ error: true });
  });
}
componentWillUnmount () {
  navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. this.state.error is not set to true at all but in render it is true? Or it is set to true somewhere else? Are you sure componentDidMount doesn't set it to true?

Comment: Have you checked what is the actual error you are getting? Since the state.error is true in render function it means that the error callback is called and success callback giving you the position most like is not. Also you probably should make the watchID an instance variable.